# Node.js - process.exit AND append the entire console.log messages in a text file

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm a noob to Puppeteer.
I'm using a script that login to a site. If username or password is wrong, I want to log the console message in a file AND exit with an error number. This number is important because it will be used in Excel VBA.
I use a file batch (Windows) to run the node.js script, and I use a function at the beginning the script to append the console message.

I run a batch file to run the script:

```
node C:\*my-path*\node-script.js
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

I can see the message in the console, but in the log file there isn't the entire error message because process.exit(1) close the procedure before it.

This is the function to append the console.log messages:

```
fs.unlinkSync("./tmp/node-js.log");
console.log = function(msg) {
    fs.appendFile("./tmp/node-js.log", msg+'\r\n', 'ascii', function(err) {
        if(err) {
            return trueLog(err);
        }
    });
    trueLog(msg);
```

---

And then, this is the code to login:

```
await page.goto('https://google-wrong.com/', {  //a wrong url to test
                waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
                timeout: 10000
}).catch(error => {
    throw (console.log('\r\n'+ 'JAVASCRIPT * Wrong Url ! * ' + error)), process.exit(1) });
```

So, if I use browser.close() instead of process.exit(1) I can append the entire message but can't exit with an error code; this is my console.log:

```
> Open browser in memory... Done!
> Connect to google-wrong.com... Error!
> JAVASCRIPT * Wrong Url ! * Error: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED at https://google-wrong.com/
```

And at the Dos prompt I see:

```
> exit /b 0
```

If I use process.exit(1), I can see the "exit with error" number:

> exit /b 1

...but I can't log the entire message:

```
> Open browser in memory... Done!
> Connect to google-wrong.com... Error
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance, and sorry for my bad english, I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use `fs.appendFileSync` in your `console.log` function, and no need for the `throw` keyword in the catch handler